# QVector<quint16> to cv::Mat to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, matrix, qimage

I have a problem with my conversions. A weird diagonal line appears when I crop a matrix with an odd number of pixel.

Quick description of my behavior:

1. Get 1 image from a video which will be received as a QVector of quint16
2. Transform this vector as a cv::Mat
3. Crop the image by using cv::rowRange & cv::colRange
4. Convert the cv::Mat to QImage to save it in a new file

   ```
   int bitCount = 12;

   for(int imgIdx = 0; imgIdx < nbImages; imgIdx++){
       /* Get image */
       QVector<quint16> data = fileManager->getChunkFromDataset(datasetId, imgIdx).value<QVector<quint16>>();
       cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_16U, data.data()).clone();

       /* Crop image */
       cv::Mat outImage = image.clone();
       outImage = outImage.rowRange(0, 399);
       outImage = outImage.colRange(0, 399);
   }

   ...

   /* Save images */
   foreach(cv::Mat matrix, images) {
       QImage image = QImage(static_cast<uchar*>(matrix.data), matrix.cols, matrix.rows, matrix.step, QImage::Format_Grayscale16).copy();
       mHDF5Manager->writeImage(image, datasetGroup, datasetName, bitsCount);
   }
   ```

Crop 399x399:

[image: Crop 399x399]

When I check the output image pixel by pixel, I find that the first row is fine, but a 400th pixel of that row seems to be added to the 1st pixel of the 2nd row, adding an offset of 1 pixel to it. Recursively, it will do a bigger offset on each new row, giving us a diagonal line clearely visible.

The weird thing about this, is that it works fine with an even crop, but not with an odd crop (I replace 399 by 400 and it works).

The clever way out of it would be to remove the cv::Mat conversion & stay as a QImage since I can easily crop the image & avoid a conversion, but I'm still curious about why it's not working.

Comment: Do another `clone` after you "crop" it. Both `colRange` and `rowRange` just change the header of the `Mat`, but the underlying pixel array (pointed to by `data`) stays the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does seem to fix the _step_ value I send to the QImage conversion. However, I still have the issue with a diagonal line (now it's white). I did find that even though I'm initializing my QImage with a step of 798, when I call the _bytesPerline()_ function of QImage, it returns me 800.

Comment: Finally, the problem might not even be in the code I described. I'm beginning to think it might be in the _writeImage_ function. I still added another _clone_ as specified by @DanMašek. I will update whenever I have more information on it.

Comment: Alright, it seems like the problem was 2 things. The first one was, like @DanMašek specified that I needed to clone after the "crop". The other thing was that I passed my QImage as a value instead of a reference to my _writeImage_ function. For some reason, the data was modified and I only saw it when I cropped with an odd number of pixels.